# What should I read to understand the math behind waves?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, book-recommendation, wave-equation

I'm learning differential equations and waves - following online courses and reading some textbooks - and I find that quite often, the use of Phasors, equations combining sinusoidal waves of different amplitudes and frequencies (the derivation of beats)...etc...they're explained really briefly, without a lot of diving deeper into them, and then applied.

Is there a specific "math" which I could study, or textbook I could read, that presents these subjects more explicitly? The more geometric and intuitive the math book is, the better! I tried looking for "wave mathematics" but...found mostly really advanced books. Complex Analysis didn't seem to fit either...

All and any recommendations are welcome, thank you so much!

---

**Edit:**

Books on the differential equations of waves are helpful...but, I think I'd like to start simpler.

What led me to asking this question is that it took me a long time to understand the geometric intuition for how to combine waves of the same amplitude but different frequencies (for which this - https://www.jstor.org/stable/27965328?seq=1 - helped quite a bit) and I still don't understand at all how to combine them if they have different amplitudes!

Is there not anything simpler than a differential equations approach, or pherhaps a book that DOES go into the differential equations, but also does so explaining each step, instead of skipping over the "basic" math of waves?

Thanks again.

Comment: I have some typed lecture notes from a course called "Oscillations and Waves" that I took at my university that you might find helpful. Get back to me in this comment thread and I'll set up a google drive folder.

Comment: Fourier transforms is a hugely important technique to analyze waves.

Comment: @K.defaoite that would be awesome! Thank you so much!

Comment: @DougM thank you! Is there any book which you would recommend for that? Or...perhaps a pre-requisite for Fourier Transforms? What led me to asking this question was that I didn't understand the geometric intuition behind combining sine waves of different frequency, and also I've only just started thinking of sine and cosine waves as projections of spinning vectors onto axes in the last few months! Thanks again.

Comment: @joshuaronis Here you go :
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bPJamoBzmSzXxj-Re8DpWdcW_z7u8hUO?usp=sharing

Enjoy:)

Comment: 3blue1brown has a interesting video that provides a neat introduction to Fourier Transforms.  There are entire courses on-line on the subject, and many many books.  You should probably learn complex analysis before you jump too deep into Fourier analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Perceptions of what constitutes "really advanced books" is rather subjective. If you're looking for texts that go as far as covering the differential equations of wave motion, I doubt if you're likely to find anything more elementary than the following:

- [A.P. French, *Vibrations and Waves*, W. W. Norton & Company (1971)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0393099369);
- [C.A. Coulson, *Waves*, 2nd edition, Addison-Wesley Longman Ltd (1977)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0582449545).

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look at them. I didn't mean just the differential equations, but understanding things like the sum of sine waves, sum of cosine waves...etc...which I think would be considered more basic?